# Uploading image add storing on server using dropzone and cropping the image in symfony2

Tags: jquery, symfony, dropzone.js

I am new to dropzone and I want to use this `dropzone.js` to upload image into the server and before uploading to the server. I just want the image to be able to crop. I am going to use `symfony 2`.

Comment: Sure, go ahead... You don't seem to have any question in your post - this forum is not about programming things for you, it is about helping out in specific problem cases. I.e. please use google and documentations to get yourself familiar with the libraries you want to use and then just try it out - if/when you run into actual problems with the implementation you can try finding some help from SO.

Answer (score 0):

public function showScreenssAction() {

```
$uploadedFile = isset($_FILES['file']) ? $_FILES['file'] :   0;
if($uploadedFile){

$fileDoc = new UploadedFile($uploadedFile['tmp_name'], $uploadedFile['name'], $uploadedFile['type'], $uploadedFile['size'], $uploadedFile['error']);
$fileDocument  = new FileDocument();
$fileDocument->setFile($fileDoc);
$fileExt = pathinfo($uploadedFile['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$fileDocument->setFileExt($fileExt);
$fileDocument->moveFile();
```

}